# If I can't use return to exit a for...in loop, what can I use?

Tags: javascript

What's the rule with `return` in `for...in` loops? Checked [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) for any references and found none. It looks to me like it isn't allowed in `for...in` loops and the loop won't run:

```js
o = {
    color: "red",
    shape: "circle"
};

console.log(o)

for (key in o) {
    o[key] = "square";
    return
};

console.log(o);
```

What's a better way to stop executing the loop (exit the loop) like `return` and `break` seem to do in long-form for loops?

Comment: Did you read the error resulting from running your own snippet? "SyntaxError: **return not in function**". The `return` means return from a function. You are not in a function. It doesn't have anything to return from. Its unrelated to being inside a loop or not.

Comment: @BorisLipschitz — That might be an engine-specific error. I get "Illegal return statement" which is much less helpful.

Answer (score 6):

This has nothing to do with the `for` loop.

You can't `return` outside of a function.

You can use `break` to break a `for..of` loop.

```js
o = {
  color: "red",
  shape: "circle"
};

console.log(o)

for (key in o) {
  o[key] = "square";
  break;
};

console.log(o);
```

Comment: Thanks @Quentin. So a loop is not considered a function. 'return' keyword is reserved for functions?

Comment: "So a loop is not considered a function" – No, why would it be? Functions are functions.

Comment: "'return' keyword is reserved for functions?" — It doesn't make sense outside of a function. Where would you be returning **to**?

Comment: no need for the rhetoric I'm learning. Maybe you could see how a function (repeats code) and loop (repeats code) look similar to a beginner.